# Does sandbox application support incoming texts to verified number?

Tags: sinch

I'm testing out the service and it appears that sandboxed applications do not support incoming replies even if the reply is from a verified number.  Can I get that confirmed?

If that is not the case, my second question is how Sinch handles self-signed certs for the endpoint on non standard SSL ports ... in my case self-signed on 8443.

Lastly, a gripe.  As a developer I look for immediate feedback when errors occur with my integrations.  I'm not really willing to wait 24 hours for a CSV to see what happened.  Any roadmap here to timely error feedback?

Comment: Can't answer your questions. I wouldn't use a service [that sends you to a community programmer's help website](https://www.sinch.com/help/dev-support/) as their "tech support solution." We are not Sinch's tech support team, unfortunately.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a request for help from Sinch.

Answer (score 0):

To handle incoming replies you need to rent a number like most providers, you can rent a number in the dashboard https://www.sinch.com/dashboard/#/numbers assign it to your app and configure your callback for SMS.
To handle incoming sms, check out the documentation here:
https://www.sinch.com/docs/sms/#smsmessagingcallbackapi
And if you have multiple numbers assigned to you app you can set the from id in the body of the request 
{
“from”:”your rentednumber”,
“message”:”hello world”
}

You can always check the status for a particular message using the API here
https://www.sinch.com/docs/sms/#checkmessagestatus as you probably know long code delivery is only carrier delivery and not handset delivery.

If you mail me at christian@sinch.com I can hook you up with some more credits to rent a number.

Comment: I had already done these steps.  The issue was in fact self-signed and/or port 8443 which is not unusual.  I would just document this for future devs.

Comment: You are right, we should document that. Actually custom ports we do support, "not trusted certs" we don't support . I want to point out that you don't need to have a cert either if you don't want to, http is fine. And for production I suspect you have a valid cert. So http://myserver.com:1023/ should work just fine for you. If not drop drop me an email and I can have the team will look at your requests.